# ERROR while Installing dlib with GPU support

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmake, anaconda, dlib

**I've Installed Cmake, visual studio 2019 and anaconda. I'm trying to use Dlib in gpu support. But every time I try to install it, running python setup.py I get the following error.**
I'm tyring to use Dlib with GPU (CUDA) support.

```
   C:\Users\yugahang\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\dlib-master>python setup.py install --set 
    USE_AVX_INSTRUCTIONS --set DLIB_USE_CUDA

    running install

    running bdist_egg

    running egg_info

    writing dlib.egg-info\PKG-INFO

    writing dependency_links to dlib.egg-info\dependency_links.txt

    writing top-level names to dlib.egg-info\top_level.txt

    package init file 'dlib\__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)

    reading manifest file 'dlib.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'


    reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'

    no previously-included directories found matching 'tools\python\build*'

    writing manifest file 'dlib.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'

    installing library code to build\bdist.win-amd64\egg

    running install_lib

    running build_py

    running build_ext

    Building extension for Python 3.7.6 (default, Jan  8 2020, 20:23:39) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
    Invoking CMake setup: 'cmake C:\Users\yugahang\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\dlib-master\tools\python -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\Users\yugahang\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\dlib-master\build\lib.win-amd64-3.7 -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=C:\Users\yugahang\Anaconda3\python.exe -DUSE_AVX_INSTRUCTIONS -DDLIB_USE_CUDA -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=C:\Users\yugahang\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\dlib-master\build\lib.win-amd64-3.7 -A x64'

    CMake Error: Parse error in command line argument: -DUSE_AVX_INSTRUCTIONS

    Should be: VAR:type=value


    CMake Error: Problem processing arguments. Aborting.



    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "setup.py", line 261, in 
        'Topic :: Software Development',
      File "C:\Users\yugahang\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 144, in setup
        return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
      File "C:\Users\yugahang\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "C:\Users\yugahang\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "C:\Users\yugahang\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_commands`   `
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Users\yugahang\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py", line 67, in run
        self.do_egg_install()
      File "C:\Users\yugahang\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py", line 109, in do_egg_install
        self.run_command('bdist_egg')
      File "C:\Users\yugahang\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "C:\Users\yugahang\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Users\yugahang\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\bdist_egg.py", line 172, in run
        cmd = self.call_command('install_lib', warn_dir=0)
      File "C:\Users\yugahang\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\bdist_egg.py", line 158, in call_command
        self.run_command(cmdname)
      File "C:\Users\yugahang\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "C:\Users\yugahang\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Users\yugahang\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install_lib.py", line 11, in run
        self.build()
      File "C:\Users\yugahang\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\command\install_lib.py", line 107, in build
        self.run_command('build_ext')`
      File "C:\Users\yugahang\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "C:\Users\yugahang\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "setup.py", line 135, in run`enter code here`
        self.build_extension(ext)
      File "setup.py", line 172, in build_extension
        subprocess.check_call(cmake_setup, cwd=build_folder)
      File "C:\Users\yugahang\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 363, in check_call
        raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
    subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['cmake', 'C:\\Users\\yugahang\\anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages\\dlib-master\\tools\\python', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\\Users\\yugahang\\anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages\\dlib-master\\build\\lib.win-amd64-3.7', '-DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=C:\\Users\\yugahang\\Anaconda3\\python.exe', '-DUSE_AVX_INSTRUCTIONS', '-DDLIB_USE_CUDA', '-`enter code here`DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=C:\\Users\\yugahang\\anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages\\dlib-master\\build\\lib.win-amd64-3.7', '-A', 'x64']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

Is there any ways to solve this problems. First I want to know what is causing this problem.

Comment: These options are enabled by default. http://dlib.net/compile.html. I recently ran `python setup.py install` on master and cuda was enabled automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Parameter `--set` for `setup.py` should be in form

```
--set <variable>=<value>
```

This will translated for `cmake` parameter as `-D<variable>=<value>` which perfectly fits into `cmake` [synopsis](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/manual/cmake.1.html).

E.g. instead of

```
--set USE_AVX_INSTRUCTIONS
```

use

```
--set USE_AVX_INSTRUCTIONS=ON
```

---

Parameter `--no` for `setup.py` doesn't have assignment (`=<value>`) part, because

```
--no <variable>
```

is automatically translated to `cmake` parameter `-D<variable>=no`.